# How to prevent attributes access outside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined 3 attributes (public, private, and protected) and am able to access all of them from outside. How do I prevent access?

```
class Speed:
    def __init__(self):
        self.public_speed = 10
        self._protected_speed = 50
        self.__private_speed = 80


s = Speed()
s.public_speed = 20
print(s.public_speed)

s._protected_speed = 60
print(s._protected_speed)

s.__private_newSpeed = 90
print(s.__private_speed)
```

Resulting:

```
20
60
90
```

Comment: There are no private or protected attributes in Python and you simply prevent access by not accessing it.

Comment: Also did you try to print `s.__private_speed`?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent access? And prevent access to who? What do you expect to be returned if the restricted user is trying to access these?

Comment: @Brendan.H I guess he is coming from a programming language like Java where you do that.

Comment: @KlausD. But I am able to access those. right? How do I restrict accessing the variable?

Comment: You simply don't. Python does not have this concept.

Comment: You can't make Python enforce this at runtime, so you have to do it via static testing.  Use tools like `pylint` and `mypy`, get them configured to enforce the standards that you expect, and don't accept code that violates them.

Comment: @Brendan.H I just want to prevent accessing those variables outside the class. Here, seems I am able to access and modify them. Am I missing something? please explain.

Comment: Thank you @Samwise. I will explore those tools.

Comment: You can't. There is no private and protected. You are a JAVA or Android Programmer i'm sure. Please note in python those access modifiers mean nothing, and by the way there is a mistake in your code, _classname__spam.... This is the way you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to control not to modify the variables, I suggest you to use magic funcation `__setattr__()`.

If you want to let people not to see the variables. Python can not do this.